# Connecting to Azure DevOps organizations/servers?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

Please bear with me.  This may get difficult to explain/understand.  See the picture below - it will likely help a lot.

In Visual Studio when attempting to browse a repository on Azure DevOps, a dialog box pops up entitled "Connect to a Project".  It has a drop-box for "Showing hosted repositories for".  This allows selection of different accounts.  However a given account can have a number of organizations (i.e. different Azure subscriptions and Azure DevOps servers) associated with it.  For example, my Microsoft "work or school" account is used in several organizations, including some Azure B2C instances.  It used to be that VS would prompt the user for a login to each organization.  However very recently a change to VS allowed the list to be filtered, essentially allowing me to say "ignore my B2C organizations since they have no DevOps".  After filtering, the dialog box shows my email address and then shows "[Filtered]".  This is fantastic, and just what the doctor ordered in my case.  HOWEVER, now I want to edit this filter.  How/where can that be done?  I'd even be satisfied if I could simply reset it or even remove the account and re-add it.  I've tried simply adding the same account again but that does nothing.

[image: Connect to a Project]

The little "filter icon" and the "[Filtered]" are very nice, but how do I edit/reset/remove/change the filter?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the top right there is a circle with your initials, if you click there opens an popup with an opcion clear filter

[image]